# Laravel - Passing value from router to controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to pass a parameter at the end of a URL to the controller in Laravel. I have an very sparse application set up with nothing more than a couple of models and migrations. The migrations work fine.

Here is my router:

```
Route::get("/hello/(:any)", "HomeController@helloAction");
```

And here is my Controller:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function helloAction($name)
    {
        return View::make("home/index", array("name" => $name));
    }
}
```

My view then echos out the name as "Hello $name!". However when I view the page I get an exception:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

I mean surely this has to be the simplest task someone could accomplish with an MVC framework, so why is this not working and why is there such a huge lack of documentation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
Route::get("/hello/(:any)", "HomeController@helloAction");
```

to

```
Route::get("/hello/{name}", "HomeController@helloAction");
```

Here is a link to the docs explaining it: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters